# ¿Cómo mostrar registros que no existen en la tabla principal?

Tags: mysql

Tengo dos tablas:

Una de ordenes:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y otra de tipos de ordenes:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito realizar una consulta que me diga el numero total de ordenes que ha emitido cada usuario, agrupando por "ID_TIPO" y por "EXP" que es un tipo de dato booleano.

```
SELECT o.ID_USUARIO, o.ID_TIPO, O.EXP, SUM(1) AS TOTAL 
   FROM Orden AS o GROUP BY o.ID_USUARIO, o.ID_TIPO, O.EXP;
```

El resultado que me arroja es este:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero el resultado final que estoy intentando obtener sería el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es decir que aunque el usuario no haya emitido ninguna orden de un determinado tipo, se muestre el resultado en la consulta indicando que de ese tipo existe un total de 0 ordenes.

[Añado SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c7a171)

Comment: En la tabla: "tipos de ordenes" el campo `ID` está relacionado de alguna manera con alguno de los campos de la tabla: "Ordenes"?, me refiero a, que si en la primera tabla, el campo `ID_TIPO` corresponde al campo de la segunda tabla: `ID`

Comment: Si, ID_TIPO es la clave primaria de TIPOS DE ORDENES

Comment: Te recomiendo que proveas un [mcve], para eso suele ser muy util crear un fiddle en, por ejemplo, [sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/). De esa manera, cualquiera que quiera ayudarte puede probar en vivo si su respuesta funciona o no. Un saludo y bienvenido a [es.so]!

Comment: Perfecto! Un saludo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Voy a plantear tu pregunta de la siguiente forma: *queremos conocer para cada usuario y de todos los tipos de órdenes y `EXP`, la cantidad que tienen de cada una*. Por empezar deberíamos arrancar desde una tabla de usuarios y no desde la de ordenes, pero bueno.. los usuarios serían:

```
SELECT ID_USUARIO FROM Orden GROUP BY ID_USUARIO
```

Haciendo esto estamos limitados a ver solo los usuarios que han tenido alguna orden, por eso decía que aquí deberíamos usar la tabla de usuarios. Lo siguiente es: todos los tipos de órdenes y `EXP`:

```
SELECT ID, EXP
       FROM tipoorden
       CROSS JOIN (SELECT 1 AS EXP UNION SELECT 0) E
```

Con esto, generamos un conjunto de todos los `tipoorden` para cada tipo de `exp`, y por último, queremos obtener las cantidades de cada tipo, para lo cual, si, usamos tu consulta original:

```
SELECT ID_USUARIO, 
       ID_TIPOORDEN,
       EXP,
       SUM(1) AS TOTAL 
       FROM Orden
       GROUP BY ID_USUARIO, ID_TIPOORDEN, EXP
```

Si combinamos todo en una sola consulta, lograríamos, creo yo, lo que estás buscando:

```
SELECT U.ID_USUARIO,
       T.ID,
       T.EXP,
       IFNULL(C.TOTAL,0) AS TOTAL
       FROM (SELECT ID_USUARIO FROM Orden GROUP BY ID_USUARIO) U
       CROSS JOIN (SELECT ID, EXP
                         FROM tipoorden
                         CROSS JOIN (SELECT 1 AS EXP UNION SELECT 0) E
       ) T
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT ID_USUARIO, 
                          ID_TIPOORDEN,
                          EXP,
                          SUM(1) AS TOTAL 
                          FROM Orden
                          GROUP BY ID_USUARIO, ID_TIPOORDEN, EXP
        ) C
        ON C.ID_TIPOORDEN = T.ID
        AND C.EXP = T.EXP
        AND U.ID_USUARIO = C.ID_USUARIO;
```

Toma nota que agregamos un `IFNULL(C.TOTAL,0)` por que los usuarios no tiene todos los tipos de ordenes.

```
| ID_USUARIO | ID | EXP | TOTAL |
|------------|----|-----|-------|
|          1 |  1 |   1 |     2 |
|          1 |  1 |   0 |     2 |
|          1 |  2 |   1 |     0 |
|          1 |  2 |   0 |     1 |
|          1 |  3 |   1 |     1 |
|          1 |  3 |   0 |     0 |
|          1 |  4 |   1 |     0 |
|          1 |  4 |   0 |     1 |
|          2 |  1 |   1 |     1 |
|          2 |  1 |   0 |     0 |
|          2 |  2 |   1 |     0 |
|          2 |  2 |   0 |     0 |
|          2 |  3 |   1 |     0 |
|          2 |  3 |   0 |     0 |
|          2 |  4 |   1 |     0 |
|          2 |  4 |   0 |     1 |
|          3 |  1 |   1 |     0 |
|          3 |  1 |   0 |     0 |
|          3 |  2 |   1 |     0 |
|          3 |  2 |   0 |     2 |
|          3 |  3 |   1 |     0 |
|          3 |  3 |   0 |     0 |
|          3 |  4 |   1 |     0 |
|          3 |  4 |   0 |     0 |
|          4 |  1 |   1 |     0 |
|          4 |  1 |   0 |     1 |
|          4 |  2 |   1 |     0 |
|          4 |  2 |   0 |     0 |
|          4 |  3 |   1 |     0 |
|          4 |  3 |   0 |     0 |
|          4 |  4 |   1 |     1 |
|          4 |  4 |   0 |     0 |
```

El [SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c7a171/153)

Comment: Muy buena respuesta. Precisamente venía ahora a comentar al op que tendría que usar cross join :)

Comment: Gracias, @Pikoh, el producto cartesiano: un mal necesario.

Comment: Lo acabo de testear y va perfecto. No había usado hasta ahora el CROSS JOIN así que hoy me voy con algo aprendido. Buen trabajo.

Answer (score 1):

Tras tu respuesta a mi comentario, considero que estás buscando algo así:

```
SELECT o.ID_USUARIO, o.ID_TIPO, O.EXP, COUNT(to.TOTAL) AS TOTAL 
FROM Orden AS o
LEFT JOIN Tipo_Orden AS to ON o.ID_TIPO = to.ID 
GROUP BY o.ID_USUARIO, o.ID_TIPO, O.EXP;
```

El left join lo que nos permite es mostrar todos los resultados de la tabla de la izquierda(en este caso Orden) y los resultados de la derecha que cumplan la condición asignada en el `ON o.ID_TIPO = to.ID`

Comment: Eso ya lo he intentando pero no me lo soluciona porque necesito que muestre los casos que no existen y con esa consulta solo obtengo los registros guardados actualmente.

Comment: Creo que no te estoy entendiendo muy bien... Podrías añadir algo mas de información o explicar un poco mas que es lo que buscas y como hacerlo, que estoy algo espeso, Gracias

Comment: Necesito realizar una consulta que me diga el numero total de ordenes que ha emitido cada usuario, agrupadas por "ID_TIPO" y por "EXP". En la tabla "ordenes" hay usuarios que no han realizado ordenes de algunos de los tipos de ordenes que existen en la tabla "tipo de orden" y necesito que aunque no existan aún aparezcan en la tabla resultado y en la columna "total" aparezca 0 tal como viene en la imagen de la última tabla.